# Bundle ID for NotificationServiceExtension is Xamarion iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have created a NotificationServiceExtension project for Xamarin iOS project to handle the notification logic.

I have got two branches one for dev which has a bundle id `com.companyname.appname` and a test branch which has a bundle ID `com.companyname.appname.test` . When I try to build the project in test branch i get an error extension project, I believe its do with the bundleID naming in there.

What should my bundle ID for NotificationService Extension in test branch be?
`com.companyname.appname.test.companynameserviceextension` or
`com.companyname.appname.test.companyname.testserviceextension` or
something totally different from all these.

This is what I have found in the xamarin documentation.

> [!IMPORTANT] The Bundle Identifier for the service extension should match the Bundle Identifier of the main app with .appnameserviceextension appended to the end. For example, if the main app had a Bundle Identifier of com.xamarin.monkeynotify, the service extension should have a Bundle Identifier of com.xamarin.monkeynotify.monkeynotifyserviceextension. This should automatically be set when the extension is added to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right, if the bundle ID of your main project is :

```
com.companyname.appname.test
```

Then the bundle ID for NotificationService Extension should be something like:

```
com.companyname.appname.test.xxxxserviceextension
```

The bundle ID of the extension in question has to be prefixed with the bundle ID of the containing app.

Comment: What exactly should be xxxx? Thats what is not clear. Should it be appname or test or something else? Btw, I have tried both appname and test. Both does not work

Comment: @LibinJoseph I think `xxxx` can be anything there. Can you share the error message here?

Comment: My appologies. What you have is correct. My issue was that the NotificationServiceExtension project had a incorrect configuration selection in the solution properties. However I still have difficulties in getting the notification working correctly. I appreciate if you can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58585257/didreceivenotificationrequest-in-not-getting-called