# DidReceiveNotificationRequest in not getting called

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I have a xamarin forms application and ios Notification service extension is not getting called when I receive notification from server.

I have done the following things so far:

1. Have added the `mutable-content = 1` in the apns payload.
2. This is how I manipulate the apns payload in the service

```
    public class NotificationService : UNNotificationServiceExtension
    {
        Action<UNNotificationContent> ContentHandler { get; set; }
        UNMutableNotificationContent BestAttemptContent { get; set; }

        protected NotificationService(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {

        }

        public override void DidReceiveNotificationRequest(UNNotificationRequest request, Action<UNNotificationContent> contentHandler)
        {
            ContentHandler = contentHandler;
            BestAttemptContent = (UNMutableNotificationContent)request.Content.MutableCopy();

            var newAlertContent = new UNMutableNotificationContent
            {
                Body = "Body from Service",
                Title = "Title from Service",
                Sound = BestAttemptContent.Sound,
                Badge = 2
            };
            ContentHandler(newAlertContent);
        }

        public override void TimeWillExpire()
        {
        }
    }
```

3. I also have the the notification service extension bundle id done.(My app bundle id is `com.companyname.appname.test` and the extension bundle id is `com.companyname.appname.test.xxxxServiceExtension`
4. In the AppDelegate class in Finishlaunching method I also have the permission code added.

```
  UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert, (approved, err) => {
            });
```

Is there anything else that I need to do?

Comment: May be the notifications disabled for your application (You can check it in settings of iOS).

Comment: @AndrewRomanov: I get the notification coming through to the app, but it does not show the Badge or the new contents that I am changing in the DidReceiveNotificationRequest method as part of test

Comment: What's the deployment target of your extension? Make sure it is lower than the device system version which you are testing.

Comment: I now have the deployment target for the ios app set to 10.3 and notification extension to 10.2 But it still does not work. Anything else that I can check?

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint there to check if the code triggered? Here is also an [official sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/ios10-monkeynotify/) you can refer.

Comment: I have added the breakpoint , both the constructor and DidReceiveNotificationRequest method does not get called. And the DidReceiveRemoteNotification in the AppDelegate does not also get called. If i change the "mutable-content" to "content-available" DidReceiveRemoteNotification gets called as expected.

Comment: I wonder if you have to add a reference to main app? I'm not sure but there must be something not config well.

Comment: Yes, the reference is there. I even went to create a new test project to test this and same happens there as well

Comment: remove .test from bundle id

Comment: from the extension project?

Comment: Please check the tips in these two threads: [Implementing a Service Extension](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/issues/1164) and [Service Extension](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/issues/46). If you still can't make it work, can you please share the new test project here and I will check it.

Comment: I have done all thats been told in both the thread. I will upload the project to github and give u the link soon. or do u have any other way of transfering the project

Comment: Just upload it to Github and share the link here.

Comment: Here is a test project that I have created https://github.com/libin85/NotificationExtensionTest

Comment: Ok, I will check and update you later.

Comment: Can you please share the remote notification payload?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT  : Turns out that i am getting the bade count working on ios 13, but not on 11 and 12. All these while I was testing  on 12. ANy idea?

Comment: @LibinJoseph As I mentioned in the first comment, you did not change the deployment target in `NotificationTestServiceExtension`. It's still 13.1.

Comment: The target is definitely set to 10.2 . I believe its a bug with the Azure push sdk, I have just tried another provider and it works absolutely fine.

Comment: If you can confirm it, you can report an issue to Azure.

Answer (score 2):

The system executes your notification content app extension only when a remote notification’s payload contains the following information:

The payload must include the mutable-content key with a value of 1.

The payload must include an alert dictionary with title, subtitle, or body information.

Listing 2 shows the JSON data for a notification payload containing encrypted data. The mutable-content flag is set so that the user’s device knows to run the corresponding service app extension, the code for which is shown in .

Listing 2 
Specifying the remote notification payload

```
{
   “aps” : {
      “category” : “SECRET”,
      “mutable-content” : 1,
      “alert” : {
         “title” : “Secret Message!”,
         “body”  : “(Encrypted)”
     },
   },
   “ENCRYPTED_DATA” : “Salted__·öîQÊ$UDì_¶Ù∞è   Ω^¬%gq∞NÿÒQùw”
}
```

Are you sure that you specify alert key?

Comment: Turns out that i am getting the bade count working on ios 13, but not on 11 and 12. All these while I was testing  on 12. ANy idea?

Comment: @LibinJoseph also apple wrote in documentation:

"Note - 

You cannot modify silent notifications or those that only play a sound or badge the app’s icon."

Comment: @LibinJoseph
The user may change the allowed interactions at any time in system settings. Use the getNotificationSettings(completionHandler:) method to determine what interactions are currently allowed for your app. (in your main app appDelegate)

Also you could check right in iPhone settings for your app.(https://stackoverflow.com/a/24990541/9244718)

Comment: If I used the above payload format my device does not receive a notification.

Answer (score 0):

i saw something similar that drove me crazy a while back. i can't tell if what you're describing is what I was experiencing but i do remember the fix. i don't speak Xamarin.Forms, so best i can do is post the swift code, but i had to re register for notifications every time the app launched

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

   // all your other config

   UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```